# Python Copy Behaviour on Sliced Nested Lists

Tags: python, list, nested, copy, slice

I do not understand the copy behaviour for nested lists in Python when slicing. I know that I can use `copy.deepcopy()` if I want to clone everything, but I'm asking more about the design of the language here, rather than solving a problem.

This makes sense, because each element is copied during slicing:

```
foo = [0, 0, 0]
bar = foo[:]
bar[0] = -1
print(foo) # [0, 0, 0]
```

This also makes sense, because slicing the zeroth index creates a new list, filled with references to foo's sub-lists (similar to a shallow copy):

```
foo = [[0], [0], [0]]
bar = foo[:]
bar[0][0] = -1
print(foo) # [[-1], [0], [0]]
```

This however does not follow from the pattern above:

```
foo = [[0], [0], [0]]
bar = foo[:][:]
bar[0][0] = -1
print(foo) # [[-1], [0], [0]]
```

In the example above, I would have expected the output `[[0], [0], [0]]` because I have sliced both axes, and so expected that elements in the sub-lists would have been copied as well. I found a similar observation with numpy arrays.

I was wondering why is it like this?

Comment: The last two code snippets are no different, with the exception that `foo[:][:]` makes a copy of the copy (and drops the intermediate copy).

Comment: *I found a similar observation with numpy arrays.* then please provide also relevant examples showing `numpy.array` behavior you observed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have sliced both axes

No you have not. You have sliced the first axis twice. Made a copy of a copy. No difference to just a copy.

Comment: Ah yes. I have wrongly assumed that `foo[:][:]` is a special syntax which overrides the literal interpretation i.e.`(foo[:])[:]`.